# Steam GetUserStatsForGame returns Bad Request for some games

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get user stats for different Steam games. For some games, like CS:GO (appid=730), Don't Starve (appid=219740), DOTA 2(appid=570) it works, returning 200. However for other games, like Don't Starve Together (appid=322330), Tribes of Midgard (appid=858820), it doesn't work, returning 400 Bad Request.

This is an example of a request I'm trying and fails:

https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v2/?key=xxxxx&steamid=76561198056738253&appid=858820

For me is very weird to return Bad Request when the only thing I'm changing is the appid.

Does someone know what might be causing this issue? I'm starting to consider that Steam didn't implement the right response code for games that don't provide UserStats.

Comment: facing the same issue; did you find the solution @karine?